# Sync files between two users on Windows-7 Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I'm running Windows-7 enterprise on a dell Laptop, and I'd like to sync the entire user directory structure between two users.

Background: I am an existing user on the computer, and soon I'll be sharing the computer with an employee. I want everything from my account to overwrite the other, while anything he does is mirrored on mine. I'm not worried about security because nothing vital is on the computer.

Both accounts are administrators, and I have already tried to use hard links to accomplish this. However the prompt leaves me with "Access Denied". I can't use shared/public folders because of the sheer amount of files that would have to be moved/linked.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so what steps must be done to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to just use one account. However,  you can also redirect your profile folders (documents, favorites, downloads, etc.) to a common location that you both can access.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first option isn't possible because account information can also access personal payroll and such. The second option isn't workable as well because of the obscene amount that would have to me moved. It also leaves out %appdata% and such.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason why you don't just place all your documents  under `C:\Users\Public`, and update shortcuts/libraries, an applications to put there?

Comment: The reason I don't do that is there are 30-40 programs that would have to be updated.